# Поиск по базе MySQL и вставка результата в переменную?

Tags: mysql, поиск

Есть таблица **post** нужно искать в столбце **title** (например Сканлайн или Сканлайн (2017) ) и вставить в переменную $content значения столбца **id**. Прошу показать код с подключениям к базе. Заранее спасибо

Comment: начните с [этого](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php) там и примеры и всё-всё-всё. Дальше Вам понадобится [prepare](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php), потом [execute](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php), затем [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php), либо [fetch](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php) и [closeCursor](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.closecursor.php). Вот [тута](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo) отличные статьи на тему PDO. Хотя бы коннект сами для приличия напишите.

Comment: Вопрос какой-то слишком неточный... Вы хотите просто потренироваться в запросах. Тогда ставьте воркбенч и тренируйтесь на здоровье. Если хотите писать приложение , подобрали для этого бд, тогда неплохо бы понимать, на каком языке программирования, каике технологии используете... стандатный URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/имя_бд?useSSL=false". дефолтный пользователь root. пароль вы указали при установке.

Comment: тест на Денвере, нужно: по названию статьи или хотя бы одно слово совпало, выводить ее ID

Comment: Я писал "Прошу показать код"

Comment: @Даниил, вставлять переменные через sprintf - так себе совет, т. к. sql injection.

Comment: Так из за "sql injection" и нужно использовать  sprintf конечно же с mysqli_real_escape_string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хорошо, попробуем так:

Полезный материал: [SELECT](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp),
 Полезный материал: [LIKE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

> Показываю код:

**Таблица** - Нужная вам таблица в базе данных, в вашем случае "post".

**Колонка** - Нужная вам колонка в которой необходимо искать текст, в вашем случае "title".

```
$servername = "localhost"; // Имя сервера для подключения
$username = "root"; //Имя пользователя БД
$password = ""; //Пароль БД
$dbname = "stackoverflow"; //Имя БД

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Ошибка:  " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{
    echo "Подключение выполнено.</br>";
}  //Подключение, проверка на подключение.

$like = mysql_real_escape_string('Сканлайн');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ТАБЛИЦА WHERE КОЛОНКА LIKE '%".$like."%'"; //SQL запрос SELECT LIKE
$result = $conn->query($sql);   
$key = 0;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {  //Проверка есть ли такие значения
    while($row =  $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $key++;
         $content['ID №:'.$key ]  .= $row['ID']; //Вытаскиваем id записей с title где есть слово Сканлайн.
    }
} else {
    echo "Нет данных.";
}

print_r( $content); //Вывод результата.
```

> Результат будет вот таким:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> В базе данных это выглядит вот так: (Колонка ID с title "Сканлайн")

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]